# Passing Delegates (With Arguements) as Parameter

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates

**Background**

I have converted the C# code below (found in TreeViewAdv file AbortableThreadPool.cs) into VB.net code using the converter found at DeveloperFusion.com. This is a learning project and I have whittled the errors caused by the auto-conversion down to this **one error**, and I am completely lost.

**C#**

```
private void HandleItem(object ignored)
{
    WorkItem item = null;
    try
    {
        lock (_callbacks)
        {
            if (_callbacks.Count > 0)
            {
                item = _callbacks.First.Value;
                _callbacks.RemoveFirst();
            }
            if (item == null)
                return;
            _threads.Add(item, Thread.CurrentThread);

        }
        ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context, delegate { item.Callback(item.State); }, null);
    }
    finally
    {
        lock (_callbacks)
        {
            if (item != null)
                _threads.Remove(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**VB.Net**

```
Private Sub HandleItem(ByVal ignored As Object)
    Dim item As WorkItem = Nothing
    Try
        SyncLock _callbacks
            If _callbacks.Count > 0 Then
                item = _callbacks.First.Value
                _callbacks.RemoveFirst()
            End If
            If item Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If

            _threads.Add(item, Thread.CurrentThread)
        End SyncLock
        ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context, Sub() item.Callback(item.State), Nothing)
    Finally
        SyncLock _callbacks
            If item IsNot Nothing Then
                _threads.Remove(item)
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Try
End Sub
```

**The Problem**

The line:

```
ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context, Sub() item.Callback(item.State), Nothing)
```

in the VB code gives this error: *Property access must assign to the property or use its value.*

Assuming that the converter just got the syntax wrong I replaced Sub() with AddressOf and I got the error: *'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses).* However, i cannot remove the parentheses without also removing the arguement that I am passing to item.Callback (namely, item.State).  This is confirmed by the fact that when I remove (item.state), I recieve another error: *Method 'Friend ReadOnly Property Callback As System.Threading.WaitCallback' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub ContextCallback(state As Object)'.*

**The Question(s)**

1.)  A simple understanding of what the author is trying to do in that line.

2.)  A workable solution for the VB code so that it will function as the C# code was intended.

**Edit:** Some more information that I think might help.  Callback and State are ReadOnly properties of Class WorkItem, of types WaitCallback and Object respectively.  Honestly, this confuses me as that would suggest that the C# code is passing a value to a read-only property.

**Requested Information**

Here is the Class WorkItem

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading

Namespace Aga.Controls.Threading
    Public NotInheritable Class WorkItem
        Private _callback As WaitCallback
        Private _state As Object
        Private _ctx As ExecutionContext

        Friend Sub New(ByVal wc As WaitCallback, ByVal state As Object, ByVal ctx As ExecutionContext)
            _callback = wc
            _state = state
            _ctx = ctx
        End Sub

        Friend ReadOnly Property Callback() As WaitCallback
            Get
                Return _callback
            End Get
        End Property

        Friend ReadOnly Property State() As Object
            Get
                Return _state
            End Get
        End Property

        Friend ReadOnly Property Context() As ExecutionContext
            Get
                Return _ctx
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method accepts a [`ContextCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.contextcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate which takes a single parameter, but your delegate doesn't accept any parameters.

Perhaps try making your delegate accept a single parameter:

```
ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context, Sub(state) item.Callback(item.State), Nothing)
```

---

### Update

On closer inspection, it looks there are some key differences in how VB.NET handles delegates, compared to C#. Basically, it has trouble resolving the delegate from a property or field and invoke it at the same time. You can, however, call the `Invoke` method on the delegate like this:

```
ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context, Sub(state) item.Callback.Invoke(item.State), Nothing)
```

However, if you don't like directly calling a method on the delegate, I believe you'll have to use a multi-line lambda to accomplish this. Either like this:

```
ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context, 
    Sub(state) 
        Dim cb = item.Callback
        cb(item.State)
    End Sub, Nothing)
```

Or like this, which is more legible in my opinion.

```
Dim contextCallback As ContextCallback = 
    Sub(state) 
        Dim cb = item.Callback
        cb(item.State)
    End Sub
ExecutionContext.Run(item.Context, contextCallback, Nothing)
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it does not work. It does not create any new errors, it just simply continues to report: *Property access must assign to the property or use its value.*

Comment: I have edited the question to include the information you asked for.

Comment: '...but your delegate doesn't accept any parameters.'  I know, this is what is confusing me the most.  It worked in C# (even though it doesn't make sense), but doesn't in VB.

Comment: @ProtoNoob See my updated answer. I think I ran into this problem once or twice in my VB.NET days, but had forgotten about some of the finer points. It's always good to brush-up though. :)